# Disable element after having been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
<img src="images/get_info.png" onclick="do_ajax('get.php?id=5');this.src='images/get_info_disabled.png';" style="cursor:pointer;border:0;">
```

I have a list of images like this and when user clicks on it, an AJAX request will be made and the image will be changed, but how can I make the image to be clickable only once?

Comment: You want it to be clickable *only* once, or you want to prevent double-clicks (but allow subsequent single-clicks)?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It'd be really easy that way.

Comment: I want it to be clickable only once :) Sorry for my confusing writing

Comment: just remove onclick event after the first click. `document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = null;`

Comment: I have also thought about using a Javascript frameworks but are there any way to complete the task without using any extra libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `do_ajax` function so it looks like this:

```
function do_ajax(url, elem) {
    var click = elem.onclick;
    elem.onclick = null;
    // Do your Ajax stuff
    elem.onclick = click;
}
```

and then call it like:

```
<img src="images/get_info.png" onclick="do_ajax('get.php?id=5', this); this.src='images/get_info_disabled.png';" style="cursor:pointer;border:0;">
```

Comment: Aw, thanks for much for your help. It just works great now :)

Answer (score 0):

To allow the element to be clicked only once, the easiest way I could think of is:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" onclick="alert('you clicked the image'); this.removeAttribute('onclick');" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TK3Qh/) of concept.

Although I'd personally add the `this.removeAttribute('onclick');` into your function.

Answer (score 0):

> < p id="id">
>   You can do this by retreiving the element in Javascript, 
>       < /p>
>        var h = documentgetbyid("id").style.display="none";